# Cannot change form data using getElementsByName

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am building an ecommerce site on Wordpress to be used by multiple agents. At present, the page uses a standard PayPal link which includes the line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="somewhere@this-site.com">
```

My theory WAS that I could use PHP to get new user's business email address from my site, and then use javascript to change the value. For test purposes, I 'faked' the former, and so used this code ...

```
<script language="javascript">
// alert(document.getElementsByName('business').value);
document.getElementsByName('business').value='changed@paypal_address.com';
alert(document.getElementsByName('business').value);
</script>
```

IN THEORY, the page should now have a revised "business" field - but it stayed the same. So I added the second commented out alert ... which - when the page was reloaded -  came back as 'undefined'

I cannot check data via forms as there are several (un-named) forms on the page, (such as form buttons with no action field that are used as delete items from cart buttons, and the PayPal webscr form which is also un-named)

Although the code is in a footer widget, I know it's loading / running as I get the alert pop ups. It also executes PHP code within the footer as it loads the page.

Is there a restriction whereby "hidden" fields cannot be found, or altered dynamically? If so, is there any work around?? (If all else fails, will have to contact the UltraCart pugin team to see if the business name can be set at source)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setValueForElementsByName(name, value) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for(var e in elements) {
    elements[e].value = value;
  }
}

setValueForElementsByName('business', 'changed@paypal_address.com');
```

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow, and report back. If my logic is correct, var 'elements' is effectively holding a list (node list?) of all the elements found on the page, and then looping through till finds the correct one, and then setting value. 

Maybe var elements=document.getElementsByName('business') ... elements[0].value='changed@paypal_address.com' could work? ... or even elements.value= ???

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a `NodeList`. Therefore, you need to access individual items by index like

```
document.getElementsByName('business')[0].value
```

If you wish to modify multiple elements with the same name, simply iterate over them like

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('business');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].value = ...;
}
```

```js
document.getElementsByName('business')[0].value='changed@paypal_address.com';
alert(document.getElementsByName('business')[0].value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="somewhere@this-site.com">
```

Comment: Showing my ignorance of this now. Does getElementsByName('business')[0].value still apply even if the field is only mentioned once in document? My limited understanding is that the square bracket indicates a  "multi-dimentional" array syntax

Comment: Just a thought: If I change an element using javascript, does it PHYSICALLY change the data on the page, or only in memory? Currently, I'm simply viewing page source after code executed, seeing original email and thinking the change hasn't occurred. Should I expect to see the page source to change? (I'll have to test if offline and see!)

Comment: @ChrisBrown, next time you are available let us have a chat